# colordiff - how to retain color while saving to file

Tags: diff, colordiff

Is it possible to retain the color while storing the diff output in a file?

This is working and showing the colors in terminal

```
colordiff -yW 1000 --suppress-common-lines file1 file2 > tempfile
```

But when I redirect the output to a file its not showing the colors.

```
colordiff -yW 1000 --suppress-common-lines file1 file2 > tempfile
```

Comment: Add `--color=always`.

Answer (score 2):

If you *always* want color, modify your configuration file `/etc/colordiffrc` or `~/.colordiffrc` as per the comment in the default file:

```
# By default, when colordiff output is being redirected
# to a file, it detects this and does not colour-highlight
# To make the patch file *include* colours, change the option
# below to 'yes'
color_patches=no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening `tempfile` in vim. When I do this, vim colors it just as I see in the terminal output.